# Login Script to get more hits

Tags: authentication

Can I write a code to login, click on a link, logout, and repeat, to give my section more hits? I think it could a a simple script but have no idea how to start.

Comment: I'd use Selenium: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Is there a way to export selenium code for others to use without selenium?

Comment: Not that I knew, but that may be worth posting a new question.